# Update entry in MongoDB, issue with routes or form

Tags: node.js, mongodb, image, express, cloudinary

I'm trying to update my entry.

Update route looks like that at the moment.

```
  // UPDATE CAR ROUTE
    router.put("/:id", middleware.checkCarOwnership, function(req, res){
        //find and update car
        Car.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body.car, function(err, updatedCar){
           if(err){
               res.redirect("/cars");
           } else {
               res.redirect("/cars/" + req.params.id);
           }
        });
        //redirect show page
    });
```

I'm trying to update this with the form

```
<form action="/cars/<%= car._id %>/?_method=PUT" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="car[name]" value="<%= car.name %>" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="image">Image</label>
        <input type="file" id="image" name="image" accept="image/*">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="car[description]" value="<%= car.description %>" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="number" name="car[price]" value="<%= car.price %>" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="car[location]" value="<%= car.location %>" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block">Submit!</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

But it throws me some errors. I've tried some different approaches, the update route at the moment is the last working one. I know it is not correct to update all the details but I couldn't come up with any working one. 
I'm using cloudinary.

I tried to refractor my new car route which looks like that

```
router.post("/", middleware.isLoggedIn, upload.single('image'), function(req, res) {
    //get data from form and add to cars array
    cloudinary.uploader.upload(req.file.path, function(result) {
  // add cloudinary url for the image to the car object under image property
    req.body.car.image = result.secure_url;
  // add author to car
    req.body.car.author = {
        id: req.user._id,
        username: req.user.username
    };
      Car.create(req.body.car, function(err, car) {
        if (err) {
          req.flash('error', err.message);
          return res.redirect('back');
        }
        res.redirect('/cars/' + car.id);
      });
    });
});
```

But nothing works.
I think my problem is just that I can't upload the new, updated image in my form because when I use enctype="multipart/form-data" in my edit form, updating does not work at all. It might be connected to overriding POST method with PUT.

Everytime I tried something different to actually upload that image like I do in new car form, it throws me "TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined".

Comment: req.file.path is not being set.  I could help, but I can't test the problem from the limited code posted.

Comment: Okay, I managed to fix the problem :)